How to Disable Password Text Box Before Email Verification in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy?
I have created a signup and signin user flow in Azure AD B2C. However, I need to implement it using a custom policy. In the user flow, Azure AD B2C disabled all component like "Password" before the email is verified. How can I achieve this feature using a custom policy in Azure AD B2C?

What do you mean by " disabled all component like "Password""?

After updating the page layout version from 2.1.7 to 2.1.26, it worked.
